# Typedefine an enum type as structure

Tags: c, struct, enums, embedded, typedef

embedded c here. 
One of our partners sent us the API prototypes of the library functions they are using. There is an enum like :

```
typedef enum{
     val1 = 0, 
     val2 = 1, 
    [..]
} status;
```

The enum type is then typedefined as a structure:

```
typedef struct status status_t;
```

What's the meaning of this typedef? 
Has it some practical meaning?
Do I have to handle it like a regular structure? 
I think that whit this approach I can convert an enumerator to a structure and I can access a member of the structure, but I am not sure. 
Any hint would be very appreciated. 
B.R.
L.

On arm-gcc, GNU c99

Comment: This shouldn't compile.

Comment: you are right, I switched the two types typing. Edit.

Comment: Add the compiler and its version to question also.

Comment: I suspect the supplier of attempting obfuscation... Can you ask them about other reasons for doing this? Maintainability and readability seem out of question.

Comment: @Yunnosch : It need not be obfuscation - it could equally (more likely) simply be the work of more than one developer, or code developed at different times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are two different types.

Structure names are in their own namespace.  So `struct status` is different from `status`.  The former is the name of a structure, while the latter is a typedef which refers to an unnamed `enum`.

The fact that the typedef name assigned to an enum is the same as the tag name given to a struct does not mean they are associated in any way as far as the compiler is concerned.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following *valid* code:

```
typedef enum
{
     STATUS1 = 0, 
     STATUS2 = 1
} status ;


// struct tag
//         |
//         V
struct status
{
    status status ;
    //  ^    ^
    //  |    |_______
    //  |           |
    // type_name  member_name
} ;

typedef struct status status_t ;
//                       ^
//                       |
//                      Type alias
int main()
{

    // The following is valid    
    status_t status_structure ;
    status_structure.status = STATUS1 ;

    // So is this    
    struct status status ;
    status.status = STATUS1 ;


    return 0;
}
```

The type name `status` is distinct from both the member name `status` and the struct tag `status`.  Somewhere in the code given, or possibly not included but necessary, is a separate definition of a struct *also* called `status`.

In C, the struct tag on its own is not a type identifier, so there is no ambiguity `struct status` is not the same type as the enum type alias `status`.  It is not necessarily a good idea, but it is not invalid.  It would of course fail if C++ compilation were used because then for `struct status`, `status` would be a type name, so *would* clash with the enum alias `status`.